# DocuSignAPI Request Authorization Code PHP cURL Redirect Fails

Tags: php, curl, docusignapi

I'm attempting to complete "2. Configure Client and Request Authorization Code" of the DocuSign Setup and Authentication process.

Although the cURL command line example is there, no PHP code is shown. I've assembled what I believe to be the correct PHP code but the result which should be "A successful call results in the user being redirected in a browser to a standard DocuSign authentication page" does not occur.

Here is my code

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=[HIDDEN]&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=[HIDDEN]'
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: You know they offer a PHP client for their API right? https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded it and added it to the website. What am I missing here? Does having it make what I'm trying to do here unnecessary?

Comment: Yeah, as what your trying to do is handled by it, also oauth is not as simple as a few redirects, so your code is maybe the first 6 of 500+ lines of logic required to make it work..

Comment: lol... Alright thanks. Can you direct me to any documentation on how to utilize the DocuSign PHP SDK? I've been searching for two days now and I can't find any in depth guides.They have code examples on their site but only in the following languages... C#, Java, and Node.js

Comment: It seems they dont have in-depth guides for the PHP client in their documentation, but you can look at the [unit tests](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php).

Comment: Care to point me in the right direction? This has kind of been a needle haystack situation for me. I have no idea where the unit tests might be.

Comment: Its all in the [readme](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client) on the repo, inc example and link to the [tests](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php).